# DynamoDB WrapperName appearing in JSON when storing with DocumentClient

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm currently using aws-sdk Dynamo Document Client to store an object which contains a key with a value of an array like so:

```
"Category": {
    "lvl1": [
      "Foo"
    ],
    "lvl2": [
      "Foo > bar"
    ],
    "lvl3": [
      "Foo > bar > cats",
      "Foo > bar > dogs",
      "Foo > bar > fish"
    ],
  }
```

I'm using the function `.update()` from aws-sdk `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(options);`

In the database it stores as

```
"Category": {
    "lvl1": [
      "Foo"
    ],
    "lvl2": [
      "Foo > bar"
    ],
    "lvl3": [
      "Foo > bar > cats",
      "Foo > bar > dogs",
      "Foo > bar > fish"
    ],
    "wrapperName": [

    ]
  }
```

My question is where `WrapperName` comes from and how to store a pure JSON object? In the same call i'm storing 4-5 other objects which all have no addition of this empty wrappername attribute.

Thanks